# HDF5 variable length structure, of variable length (C API)

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, hdf5

I'd like to write data which is contained in a STL container to a HDF5 file. From what I gathered, I need to declare a contiguous memory block and use the `"hdf5.h"` C API to transfer the data from the memory buffer to the disk.

For regular dataspaces, the procedure is straightforward; one only needs to create temporary arrays on the stack with `new`. HDF5 "understands" such memory layouts.
It is a different story when one deals with irregular dataspaces, because the dedicated type `hvl_t` must be used.

The following snippet works but is not ISO C++(11) :

```
// Test data
std::vector< std::vector<int> > jagged_array(3);
jagged_array[0] = {0};
jagged_array[1] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
jagged_array[2] = {0, 1, 2};

hvl_t X[jagged_array.size()];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jagged_array.size(); ++i) {
    X[i].len = jagged_array[i].size();
    int * ptr = (int *) malloc (X[i].len * sizeof(int));
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < X[i].len; ++j) {
        ptr[j] = jagged_array[i][j];
    }
    X[i].p = (void *) ptr;
}
```

My C is *extremely* rusty; this snippet is almost entirely ripped off the HDF5 example page, except for the illegal line `hvl_t X[jagged_array.size()];`.

How should I go about declaring an `hvl_t` with a size determined at runtime?
It surely involves `malloc`, but I'm really stumped here.

Comment: have you tried `hvl_t * X = (hvl_t *)malloc(jagged_array.size() * sizeof(hvl_t));`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Lashane. I just tried, it yields the error 
`error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘hvl_t*’ `

Comment: thank you for posting error, I've added cast to sample

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Any insights about what's going on here? (Perhaps a blog post/article I could read).

Comment: yeah, you could read any book about c, don't use c++ books, usually this section called dynamic arrays

Comment: @JGab: If your compiler complained about the cast from `void *` to `hvl_t *`, it is not a C compiler.  C compilers do that automatically; C++ compilers do not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks for the information! You are right about the compiler. I'm using g++ (with `-pedantic`, `-Wall` and `-Wextra`) because this small C snippet is actually nested within a C++ code base. The HDF5 C++ API is not very well documented, hence the usage of a C API.

Comment: STL means standard template library.  That library is not available in C.  Perhaps the OP meant C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lashane answered in the comments:

One should simply use

```
hvl_t * X = (hvl_t *)malloc(jagged_array.size() * sizeof(hvl_t))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been some time, but I came upon this today. Here is a proper c++ solution, not allocating additional memory, but just storing the pointer to the vectors in the `vlen_t`:

```cpp
// Test data
std::vector< std::vector<int> > jagged_array(3);
jagged_array[0] = {0};
jagged_array[1] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
jagged_array[2] = {0, 1, 2};

hvl_t X[jagged_array.size()];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jagged_array.size(); ++i) {
    X[i].len = jagged_array[i].size();
    X[i].p = (void*) &jagged_array[i].front();
}
```